# Changing Image Picker Preferred Status Bar Style swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, uistatusbar

the status bar style for my application is white except when image picker controller is presented and  I have already extend my `UINavigationController` but it doesn't seem to be working on any view present only on pushed views does anyone have solution??

```
extension UINavigationController {
    open override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return topViewController?.preferredStatusBarStyle ?? .lightContent
    }
}
```

I have also try this method , but the navigationController is a let and the 
`preferredStatusBarStyle` is read-only

```
   func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        viewController.navigationItem.title = "willShow"
        navigationController.preferredStatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you present something modally and you want it to determine the status bar style you need to set `modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true`

For example:

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MyViewController())
navigationController.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
present(navigationController, animated: true)
```

You'll also need to check if the current `UINavigationController` is a `UIImagePickerController` and return `.lightContent` from `preferredStatusBarStyle` as `UIImagePickerController` has a prefers the `.default` out of the box.

```
open override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    if self is UIImagePickerController {
        return .lightContent
    }
    return topViewController?.preferredStatusBarStyle ?? .lightContent
}
```

Comment: I dont understand why do I need to set  rootViewController: MyViewController() when I want to show UIImagePicker?

Comment: and using rootViewController  with  UIImagePicker will crash the app 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'

Comment: That was just an example. You just need to set `modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance` whenever you want the presented view controller to determine the status bar style. If you're presenting a `UIImagePickerController`, set it on the instance of that that you're presenting.

Comment: I did but it still black "        imagePicker.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
"